# Unicode expression failing in preg_match after php and apache update

Tags: php, regex, apache, unicode, preg-match

I have an old configuration of a LAMP server running three-four year old apache+php+ubuntu10, and a new production one in preparation for updating everything with the latest php 5.5.9 and apache/2.4.7 running on ubuntu 14.

On the site I have a preg_match evaluating an expression in order to parse some urls that have both ASCII and unicode based urls. I don't have too much options of touching and changing the actual expression, but I can manipulate the test string.

For this question I have the following expression which returns true on the old server but fails on the production site:

```
preg_match('#^/(?<controller>[-_a-zA-Z\p{L}]+)$#','/Гtest')
```

However, non unicode strings evaluate to true on the production site such as this line:

```
preg_match('#^/(?<controller>[-_a-zA-Z\p{L}]+)$#','/test')
```

Also the production site evaluates the expression correctly to true if I remove the ^ (Beginning of string) and $ (end of string) in the expression as such:

```
preg_match('#/(?<controller>[-_a-zA-Z\p{L}]+)#','/Гtest')
```

Is there a server config I have to change, or anything else I can do to get the first example to work on the production site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unicode matching you need to use /u :

```
preg_match('#^/(?<controller>[-_a-zA-Z\p{L}]+)$#u','/Гtest')
```

In your example you havnt unicode in regexp, so you can skip it, but always keep this in mind.

As also you need to define your php environment. You can do this thru php.ini:

```
mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
```

Or add this string on top of your php:

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
...
```